# ASP.NET Rendering SDK with CM on the IIS site is throwing 500 error

Tags: jss-rendering-sdk

`ASP.NET Rendering SDK` with CM on the IIS site is throwing `500 error` and no custom code, it is plain vanilla empty site with style guide comes with SDK install.
We are NOT using docker. `Sitecore 10.3` and `Headless 21.0`. Tried using IIS express and rendering was hosted on IIS as well, same issue.

Sitecore documentation doesn't have any setup instructions for non-docker asp.net core SDK so I have used command "`dotnet new sitecore.aspnet.gettingstarted -n MyProject`" and ***extracted the rendering folder to run it outside of docker***. Here is the docker documentation link https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the right .Net version selected in your Application pool.

Comment: @rvsure Please elaborate right .net version ? I tried using IIS express in VS and no managed code apppool etc, it didn't work. Please advice the setting you would like to try